# Invalid use of group function when using count() MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get the average amount of orders per customer and I've tried a bunch of things but I can't find an answer that works to this particular problem.

With pretty much everything I've tried I get Error 1111: Invalid use of group function.

Results on google are only talking about not using where statements so I'm a little lost.

```
DELIMITER //
create function avgAmount()
returns double
BEGIN
DECLARE AvgAmountOfOrders double;
SET AvgAmountOfOrders =  (COUNT(DISTINCT orderID)  * 1.0) / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID), 0)  ;
return AvgAmountOfOrders;
END;//
DELIMITER ;

Select avgAmount();
```

Comment: `COUNT` is a function that can be used in a SQL statement, not outside one. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you The Impaler.
For anyone interested this was the solution.

```
DELIMITER //
create function test123()
returns double
BEGIN
DECLARE AvgAmountOfOrders double;
SET AvgAmountOfOrders =  (select COUNT(DISTINCT OrderID  * 1.0) / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID), 0)from orders)   ;
return AvgAmountOfOrders;
END;//
DELIMITER ;

Select test123();
```